# Load balancing dynamic php site using nginx

Tags: php, nginx, load-balancing, sticky-session

I have three servers. One for load balancing other two for serving web application. My load balancing works fine if i use my web page as static site. but when i log into my web page it does not respond correctly because every time it changes its server when the page loads. how can i do it without changing current server before log-out. My load balancing server configuration is

```
upstream web_backend{
    server 192.168.33.2;
    server 192.168.33.3;
}

server{
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://web_backend;
    }
}
```

Comment: i suggest asking on server fault http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Session persistence](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html) feature of nginx:

> If there is the need to tie a client to a particular application
>   server — in other words, make the client’s session “sticky” or
>   “persistent” in terms of always trying to select a particular server —
>   the ip-hash load balancing mechanism can be used.
>
> With ip-hash, the client’s IP address is used as a hashing key to
>   determine what server in a server group should be selected for the
>   client’s requests. This method ensures that the requests from the same
>   client will always be directed to the same server except when this
>   server is unavailable.
>
> To configure ip-hash load balancing, just add the ip_hash directive to
>   the server (upstream) group configuration:

In your case just add `ip_hash` into your upstream definition

```
upstream web_backend{
    ip_hash;
    server 192.168.33.2;
    server 192.168.33.3;
}
```